# Unable to pull Tar files from Jfrog Artifactory when file size is over 7gb

Tags: curl, artifactory, jfrog-cli, tarfile

We have tried with the JFrog CLI and the `curl` command but unable to pull the tar files, it is failing around 5-6gb, below are the errors.

Using Jfrog CLI

```
$ jf rt dl /tarFile /mnt/sdc.tar --server-id=1 --retries=6 --quiet --flat --threads=1

[Warn] [Thread 0] [2]: (Attempt 7) - Failure occurred while downloading part 2 of https://artifactUrl/artifactory/tarFile: open /tmp/jfrog.cli.temp.-1668500133-936929090/2_3393945811: no space left on device
[Info] [Thread 0] [2]:  executor timeout after 6 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
[Error] [Thread 0]  Received an error: open /tmp/jfrog.cli.temp.-1668500133-936929090/0_261788985: no space left on device
[Error] open /tmp/jfrog.cli.temp.-1668500133-936929090/0_261788985: no space left on device
[Error] open /tmp/jfrog.cli.temp.-1668500133-936929090/0_261788985: no space left on device
```

Using `curl`

```
$ curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:ApiKey" https://artifactUrl/artifactory/tarFile -O /mnt/downloads/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
13 7468M   13  974M    0     0  9861k      0  0:12:55  0:01:41  0:11:14 6639k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (1227 != 1400)
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

We are trying to pull the Tar file but unable to pull.

Answer (score 1):

The below message

```
[Error] open /tmp/jfrog.cli.temp.-1668500133-936929090/0_261788985: no space left on device
```

indicates that there is no space for Artifactory to materialise and give it to user/client. Make sure, there is enough space for Artifactory to download it.

You can validate with storage commands like df -h

Comment: although we are having space in our local machine, we are still facing the same issue, we want to know if there is any limitation in Jfrog, if yes, how can we overcome that.

Comment: The space should be available on Artifactory server where the artifactory is running.